# Conditional Moment Generating Function and Iterated Rule

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, moment-generating-functions

Let $N$ by the number of claims made by a person.  Assume that the Number of claims varies with the type of person.  Measure the type of person by a  second random variable $\Lambda$, which is nonnegative and follows some distribution $F$.  Further, assume $N$ conditioned on $\Lambda =\lambda$ follows a Poisson with mean $\lambda$.

Find the distribution of $N$ using the MGF technique; that is, express it as a function of the MGF of $\Lambda$.
Find the exact expression of the MGF of $N$ if $\Lambda$~$GAMMA(\alpha, \beta)$, and conclude the distribution of $N$ using the uniqueness theorem.

So here's where I've made it so far:

$$M_N(t)=E(e^{tN})=E(E(e^{tN}|\Lambda))=E(e^{\Lambda(e^t-1)})=M_\Lambda(e^t-1)$$
So if if $\Lambda$~$GAMMA(\alpha, \beta)$, we have that $$M_N(t)=\frac{1}{(1-\beta e^t+\beta)^\alpha}$$
But I do not recognize this MGF, which suggests that I didn't do something correctly somewhere.  Do you recognize this MGF?  If not, what is my mistake?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $M_{\Lambda}(t)=(1-t/\beta)^{-\alpha}$ is the MGF of your Gamma variable, then $$M_N(t)=M_{\Lambda}(e^t-1)=\left(\frac{\beta}{\beta+1-e^t}\right)^{\alpha}$$
$$=\left(\frac{q}{1-pe^t}\right)^{r},$$
using the substitution $\beta=q/p$, $q=1-p$ and $r=\alpha$. We note that this is the MGF of a [Negative Binomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution#Gamma%E2%80%93Poisson_mixture) RV.

Comment: Genius!  I wish I could see these things.  Thank you so much!

Comment: @ereHsaWyhsipS You're welcome! I am flattered and suppose my answer makes it seem like I magically identified the MGF but I did not...I just knew from the context of the given Poisson-Gamma mixture that you'd end up with a Negative Binomial distribution. So, I looked up its MGF and confirmed the match with the substitution--after a few failed attempts.